# How to manage time of audio in html?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
let mySong = new 
Audio("_Dard_Dilo_Ke_Full_Song_(Audio)__Himesh_Reshammiya,_Yo_Yo_Honey_Singh(128k).m4a");
console.log((mySong.duration)/60);
</script>
```

This song is of 4.24 minutes but when i console log the the same song's duration is shows 4.40 minutes .
How to deal with this

Comment: Use duration property instead: `var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").duration;`

Comment: nothing changes remains same

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are dividing it by 60 (you want to convert it to minutes). There is no need to. You simply can get the duration by this

```
`var obj = document.createElement('video');
  console.log(obj.duration); `
```

Or if you want to update the time:

```
    duration = parseInt( audio.duration ),
    currentTime = parseInt( audio.currentTime ),
    timeLeft = duration - currentTime,
```

You can convert it to minutes and second like this one:

```
   second = timeLeft % 60;
   mintues = Math.floor( timeLeft / 60 ) % 60;
```

Comment: point i why i am not getting actual duration for audio why it is greter than what i hava